# SpeechSynthesizer throws System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-to-speech

I want to generate text-to-speech files and this is what I have:

```
SpeechSynthesizer TheSpeechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

TheSpeechSynthesizer.Rate = 1;
TheSpeechSynthesizer.Speak("Hello");

TheSpeechSynthesizer.SetOutputToWaveFile(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "\\ClientFiles\\test.wav");
TheSpeechSynthesizer.SetOutputToWaveFile("c:\\test.wav");
```

The moment the debugger hits line 2, it throws System.InvalidOperationException

Edit: the error log is as follows:

> System.InvalidOperationException Inner Exception: Asynchronous
>   operations are not allowed in this context. Page starting an
>   asynchronous operation has to have the Async attribute set to true and
>   an asynchronous operation can only be started on a page prior to
>   PreRenderComplete event. Inner Source: System.Web Inner Stack Trace:
>   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.OperationStarted() at
>   System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.VoiceSynthesis..ctor(WeakReference
>   speechSynthesizer) at
>   System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.get_VoiceSynthesizer() at
>   System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.set_Rate(Int32 value) at

How could I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Something wrong with namespaces or System.dll version referenced in your project. Your code works fine for me.

Comment: I'm using System.Speech.Synthesis